# shadowsocks client was injected some poison code?

Tags: proxy

I have found an old version and latest version of shadowsocks (downloaded from shadowsocks.org site, not qt5version) have create a lot of connections underground.

---

Here is final conclusion, it is was injected !!

i am using wireshark to hostname and src ,src port / dest & dest port
and using netstat -nao to get pid (process name is ss_privoxy or Shadowsocks
find the process name by PID

### shadowsocks control by 162.244.35.22 United States, California, Fremont king-servers.com

### [image: check by wireshark]

so, I check the server log,
I guess those connections are "cheating click" connection, or "fake user" connection or "password crack" connection.

somebody said i using global proxy.

**U could check my qt5 snapshot: it is very clean when i switch to qt5. So it is no related to "global proxy", also i am known if i am visiting 12306**

**Here is my questions:**

- Are those old and lastest version were infected?
- Why there is no underground connections of old version on the other
  machine?

  1. old version of ss connection

[image: old version of ss connection]

2. latest version of ss connection

[image: latest version of ss connection]

3. shadowsocks server logs

[image: shadowsocks server logs]

4. shadowsocks server logs

[image: shadowsocks server logs]

5. swith qt5, it is very clean, no underground connection

[image: swith qt5, it is very clean, no underground connection]

6. swith qt5& open some google web site

[image: swith qt5& open some google web site]

[image]

Comment: You can upload samples to analyse.

Comment: It seems that you are using global proxy?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You are using proxy for your all connections , and you visited these website.
2. You are listening on a public port , or your password is too weak , your server was scanned by hackers and added to free or paid proxy list website.

Shadowsocks is still open source, it just not on the default branch , switch to "Master" to view source code.

Answer (score 0):

seems that you tunneled connections to china sites through shadowsocks as well.

Actually the source codes for latest version are still there. I tried shadowsocks-libev on my Linux desktop and netstat reported nothing weird.

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like that you are using SS to proxy all your connections.

Answer (score 0):

It's just look like you proxy all sites.

Verify hash is need whenever you downloaded a file.

Are u using Shadowsock or ShadowsocksR?

Comment: if proxy all site &  i quit ss, proxy was set empty , all connections should aslo be capture by Net monitor, but their is no underground connections "like 12306 connecxtion.

Comment: and More, if i switch to the "qt5" ss .version. there is no underground connections